# Why doesn't position_dodgev always work on my errorbars in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why isn't `position_dodgev(height=pd)` having any effect in the top code/graph, but working as intended in the bottom (but moving `linetype=` up a level messes up the errorbar linetype [I just want solid errorbars])?

Prereqs

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggstance)
a3<-structure(list(period = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), warning = c(1, 2,1, 2, 1, 2), m = c(37, 38, 36, 39, 38, 40), sd = c(6, 6.6, 6.1, 6.8, 6.4, 6.4), upper.SD = c(43, 44.6, 42.1, 45.8, 44.4, 46.4), lower.SD = c(31, 31.4, 29.9, 32.2, 31.6, 33.6)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(period = c(1, 2, 3), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
a3$period<-as.factor(as.character(a3$period))  
pd=0.1
```

Bad dodge, good linetype on errorbars:

```
ggplot(a3[,], aes(x=m, y=warning)) +
  geom_path(size=1,position = position_dodgev(height=pd),aes(linetype=period))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,5,4))+
  labs(linetype="")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position=c(0,0), legend.justification=c(-.25,-.25))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=lower.SD, xmax=upper.SD),position = position_dodgev(height=pd),
                 show.legend=FALSE)
```

[image]

Good dodge, bad linetype on errorbars:

```
   ggplot(a3[,], aes(x=m, y=warning,linetype=period)) +
      geom_path(size=1,position = position_dodgev(height=pd))+
      scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,5,4))+
      labs(linetype="")+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(legend.position=c(0,0), legend.justification=c(-.25,-.25))+
      geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=lower.SD, xmax=upper.SD),position = position_dodgev(height=pd),
                     show.legend=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to tell the error bar layer which variable represents the overlap.  Since you don't want `linetype` to be set globally, try using `group = period` in the error bar layer

Comment: @aosmith nail on the head

Comment: One of the two of you (@Anomie or @aosmith) should post this explanation as an answer ...

Comment: I think these duplicates should cover it, setting `group` correctly for errorbars, but I can reopen if deemed necessary.